# Find Coincidences on a Matrix

Tags: excel, if-statement, matrix, find, vlookup

I'm trying to create a formula for the following issue.

I have one sheet with two columns:

- A Spare_part_code which are alphanumeric codes
- B Part_type which is just a letter from A to E. (we assign the importance f a part based on the letter, being A most important and E less important)

Then on another sheet, I have a list of repairs, one per line that have in lines from G to X the parts used on that repair.

I would like to, per repair, have a formula that search among all the parts used on that repair, and return the level of the parts used, but only the Letter of the most important part, for example:

For repair XXXXX I have used 10 parts, and all of them are E type, except one which is B, so In this case I need to show B on the result
For repair YYYYY I have used 3 parts, all of them A, so I need the formula to return A.

Comment: Check whether my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is the final output you needed.

Add this formula in cell F2 and Drag down. I have written the formula from column G to X as you have requested.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G2:X2,"A"),"A",IF(COUNTIF(G2:X2,"B"),"B",IF(COUNTIF(G2:X2,"C"),"C",IF(COUNTIF(G2:X2,"D"),"D",IF(COUNTIF(G2:X2,"E"),"E","NA")))))
```

[image: Result]